# GNU Parallel not using all processors

Tags: gnu-parallel

I am using GNU parallel to speed up a process. However, GNU parallel does not use all cores on my machine. I wonder what the limiting factor here is.

The command:

```
find data -type f | parallel --pipe -P 70 python program.py > output
```

However, it only uses 4 of 70 cores. I wonder if anybody knows if there are other limitations that make it only use 4 cores.

Comment: What is `-P 70` doing? Try removing that. What computer has 70 cores?

Comment: If you have a weird machine (with 70 cores) you could check `parallel` sees all your cores with `parallel --number-of-cores`

Comment: @MarkSetchell It has 72, I thought I leave two for whatever other things I am doing. 72 is also returned by `parallel --number-of-cores`. But it seemed to work when I use --xargs instead of --pipe, but I needed to rewrite program.py for it to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not know that `program.py` does. But it is very uncommon to use `--pipe` together with `find`. So I think this is what you want:

```
find data -type f | parallel -P 70 python program.py > output
```

With `--pipe` the output from `find` must be atleast 70 MB for this to run 70 jobs in parallel because the default `--block-size` is 1 MB:

```
find data -type f | parallel --pipe -P 70 python program.py > output
```

IF `program.py` really reads filenames on stdin, then you should probably use `--round-robin` with a smaller `--block`:

```
find data -type f | parallel --pipe --block 1k --round-robin -P 70 python program.py > output
```

This will takes the input from `find` and give the first 1kByte to the first job, the 70th kByte to the 70th job, and the 71st kByte to the first job.